# How to remove default maximum word limit (maxlength) from <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea

I'm using a `<textarea>` field to get inputs from clients.

By default the `maxlength` for `<textarea>` is 524288.
Source: [Maxlength for Textarea](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-textareamaxlength-attribute/)

I want the `<textarea>` to be **limitless** because clients want to use it to process large bodies of text.

How can this be achieved?

What I tried:

I have used `maxLength={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}`. This will set the `maxlength` to maximum safe integer in JavaScript (9007199254740991).

I'm looking for other better approaches.

Comment: Why are you looking for other better approaches if the one you use works? It looks like that IS the approach if it works

Comment: Also a better approach is to upload a file instead of relying on the browser to handle such large texts

Answer (score 1):

The [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#limiting-user-input-length:-the-maxlength-attribute) does not specify the maximum limit for `maxlength` by default. However, there are technical limitations of various browsers related to performance. For example, the same Chrome has a limit of `maxlength` = 2147483647, as in the example below:

```js
const element1 = document.querySelector('#example-1');
const element2 = document.querySelector('#example-2');
console.log('maxlength element #1 (=2147483647):', element1.maxLength);
console.log('maxlength element #2 (=2147483648):', element2.maxLength);
```

```html
<textarea id="example-1" maxlength="2147483647"></textarea>
<textarea id="example-2" maxlength="2147483648"></textarea>
```

If you need to work with such a large text, you should take a closer look at using [contenteditable="true"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable), but at the same time, try to avoid using performance-heavy CSS styles. Example below:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">...there should be a lot of text here...</div>
```

But purely from the performance side, perhaps you should look at the possibility of loading such a large text as a stream (including a file stream), with partial display of it on the screen, for better performance.